# Searchbox don't return any results

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to make a search on my sql database, but it doesn't return anything. When i use `var_dump`  it gives me "string(0)"" "My PHP code seems to be alright, can anyone help me figure it out ?

The codes:

functions.php:

```
function buscarCarros($pConexao, $nome){
    $carro = array();
    $query = "SELECT nome FROM carros WHERE nome = ?";

    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($pConexao, $query)) {

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $nome);

        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $nomeResultado);

        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
            $carro[] = $nomeResultado;
        }

        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    return $carro;
}
```

result_pesquisa.php:

```
<?php
    include('header.php');
    include_once('menu.php');
    include_once('conecta.php');
    include_once('functions.php');

$nome = $_REQUEST['pesquisas'];

$carro = buscarCarros($conexao, $nome);
foreach ($carro as $carros) {
    echo $carros['nome'];
}
?>
```

and the searchbox, the menu.php:

```
<nav class="twelve columns">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="comprar.php">Comprar</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Vender</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Contato</a></li>
    </ul>
    <form id="searchbox" action="result_pesquisa.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" class="search-top remove-bottom" name="pesquisas" placeholder="Qual carro você procura?">
        <!-- <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('searchbox').submit();"> -->
        <a href="result_pesquisa.php"><span class="icon-top icon-search"></span></a>
    </form>
</nav>
```

Comment: How is the data being "submitted"? I don't see a submit button or any onchange listener. Are you relying on just `<a href="result_pesquisa.php">`? If so, that won't work. It needs an argument passed to it, or use a submit button. All you're presently doing, is calling the "result_pesquisa.php" file.

Comment: I just click the button, there's a way to make the search button work like a submit button ? If you wanna see what i mean, here it is: gabrielozzy.zz.vc/newcars

Comment: Replace the link `<a href="result_pesquisa.php">` with `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">`

Comment: I have to go, good luck with that.

Comment: It still didn't worked, the search button has changed and still, don't return any result...

Answer (score 0):

As I do not have enough reputation yet to comment I will write my suggestion here.

The SQL seems a bit weird to me. `SELECT nome FROM carros WHERE nome = ?`. To me it seems you are selecting the only thing you already know.

The other thing I would try is to use the $_POST super global instead of the $_REQUEST global as the latter is affected by PHP during startup of each request. [Documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php).

The PHP itself seems good (it is nice to see someone using prepared statements...great!) and the HTML is valid according to the [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/) assuming you are declaring doctype and character encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: nome is a column in my table carros, i don't know, there's a way we could make it better ? And bout the $_POST... still didn't worked :/

Comment: It is just that it seems to me the sql query is obsolete as you request some information you already have. I dont know that (spoken) language this is written in so I could be wrong.

Comment: I just ordered the DB to select the column nome from the table carros where the value is unknow (since it will be informed by the user), it seems to be correctly, i just don't know why it don't return anything...

Comment: Try replacing the sql query with `SELECT * FROM carros WHERE nome = ?`. Notice the `*` character which means select everything and see what is returned. Also try enabling full error reporting by using `error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: It gave me this error: Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_result() [function.mysqli-stmt-bind-result]: Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in /home/u374984363/public_html/newcars/functions.php on line 62

Comment: How many columns do you need information from and what are their names?

Comment: Just the column nome, from the table carros.

Comment: Okay then try to revert back the change `*` to `nome`, so the query is as you posted it. If you [read](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) the examples section on the documentation it appears you have to provide as many variables to the function as you select.

Comment: Also try to check the return value of `mysqli_stmt_execute` and try   to dump the mysqli error state by using `var_dump(mysqli_error());`

Comment: What's the best way to check the return of that value ? There's a code for it or something like it ?

Comment: Change the line that says `mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);` to `$val = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);` and then dump the result with `var_dump($val);`

Comment: It returned this to me: bool(true)

Comment: Hnm... Cant figure it out at the moment. I will get back to you if I get an idea.

Comment: Have you tried dumping the mysqli error state? Use `var_dump(mysqli_error());` for that and send me the result.

Comment: Did it, and received this: Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /home/u374984363/public_html/newcars/functions.php on line 61
NULL

Comment: That is my bad. I forgot to mention you need to provide the current mysqli connection. The script should look like the following: `var_dump(mysqli_error($link));`. Here `$link` is the mysqli connection. Be sure to read the official PHP documentation whenever you encounter problems of any kind to troubleshoot the most common errors. The comments section too can give you valuable information as well. [Documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: Right... it returned me this: string(0) "" but, if the field exists, why i have this return ?